# Spreadsheet program

Tags: java, serialization, spreadsheet

I'm required to design and implement (using Java language) the functionality 
for the spreadsheet to a “create new” spreadsheet. Also, implement the “load” and “store” 
capabilities from/to persistent storage. It is required that the functionality applicable for individual cells, column of cells, row of cells, and region of cells must be maintained correctly.

Can I use Object Serialization to implement these functions "load" and "store"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use Object Serialization to implement these functions "load" and "store"?

Simple answer: **Yes.**

Object serialization can be used to store objects to persistent storage and object deserialization can be used to load objects from persistent storage. See e.g. [Introduction to Object Serialization](http://www.javabeginner.com/uncategorized/java-serialization).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use object serialization to implement the load and store functions, provided you have a Spreadsheet class that implements all of your other requirements, and the [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Make a simple class to represent the spreadsheet with all of the data for it within. Then, in your save method, open an ObjectOutputStream on the file you'll be saving to. use the stream to save your spreadsheet object. To open/load, Open an ObjectInputStream and load the object, casting it as a spreadsheet object. Then sit back with a cold brew and marvel at the glory of Java.